# Get records of table if user exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using this codeigniter active record query in my model to get the top 10 users in my user table with the most points.

```
$this->db->order_by('points', 'desc'); 
        $q=$this->db->get('user', 10);
        $data = $q->result_array();
        return $data;
```

This works fine and returns information on the top 10 users with the most points. `points` being a column in my `user` tabel.

However I have been trying to get the top 10 users who also exist in another table `entries`.

In the entries table, the user_id og the current user is stored when a user makes an entry.

I want to get the top to users who have enetered. So I want to alter the query above to return the 10 users with most points, who are in the `entries` table.

```
User Table:

id, name, points

Entries Table:

id, time_entered, image, user_id
```

How do I do this?

I tried a join and it just returned the single user with the most points.

Comment: How does your `user` table and `entries` table look like?

Comment: @Jhn Please see above edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope your entries table have user_id as foreign key.

So your code should be:

```
$this->db->select("user.*,entries.*");
$this->db->from("user");
$this->db->join("entries","user.id = entries.user_id");
$this->db->order_by('user.points', 'desc'); 
$this->db->limit(10);   
$q = $this->db->get();    
$data = $q->result_array();
return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CI but I'll try to give a MySQL query instead,

```
SELECT * from user AS u 
    WHERE u.id IN (
        SELECT e.user_id from entries AS e
    )
    ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10
```

Just convert it to CI AR Query. I think CI has some ways to set the `condition` of an AR query. If there is that option, you can just set the condition to `IN` to determine if the `u.id` exists in your entries table.